# How to install pdftk on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, pdftk

I want to install pdftk with MacPorts, but this command does not work:

```
 sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Is it possible to install it on a Mac?

My system specifications are:

```
Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory:    8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics:  Intel HD Graphics 4000 768 MB
```

Comment: `apt-get` is for linux, have you tried `sudo port install pdftk`?

Comment: yes, you are right. i made mistake.Great!

Comment: PyPDF2 provides an alternative script `pdfcat` https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/Easy%20Concatenation%20Script.html just in case people still get attracted here from google search result.

Comment: You can install it from the official site https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/

Comment: 2021 Jan 12: Only thing that worked on macOS Big Sur was the link from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889993/293280. Using the download link from the official website downloads an old installer and you get a `zsh: bad CPU type in executable: pdftk` error.

Comment: **2022 Update**: This worked for me: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.02-mac_osx-10.11-setup.pkg

Comment: 2022 Sept 13 : original author of pdftk posted this PKG here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248310/3553808 , and this worked on macOS Monterey (12.5.1).

Comment: To install it using homebrew (as of october 2022), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74058620/5805552

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use [the official installer](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) from PDF Labs.

<strike>**Edit:** It’s now available through [homebrew-cask](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask) too. If you have that installed, you can just run</strike>

```
brew cask install pdftk
```

to install pdftk.

There is [no longer a Cask package available](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/7707), so you will have to defer to the original solution or [follow this workaround](https://gist.github.com/jvenator/9672772a631c117da151)

Comment: just adding something that came up to me - I needed run  
`brew update && brew upgrade brew-cask`

Comment: @JonatasCD Thanks for the command. It worked after I updated and upgraded.

Comment: An anonymous user points out that pdftk has temporarily been removed from homebrew-cask due to [this issue](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/7707). Follow that link for more information.

Comment: It is not working anymore.

Comment: @Puce I get an error trying to install also. What is the best way to install it?

Comment: @covard In our project decided to use a pure Ubuntu VM through Vagrant as pdftk and other plugins have issues in Mac.

Comment: @covard Have you tried the PDF Labs installer I mentioned at the beginning of the answer?

Comment: Here's a [step-by-step copy-paste `brew cask install pdftk` workaround](https://gist.github.com/jvenator/9672772a631c117da151) -- worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @JoelPurra I [forked the gist](https://gist.github.com/scottgwald/631123afbe3038bc3ed4) and added all the commands to a script. That can be run instead of doing 15 copy-pastes.

Comment: @scottgwald: didn't have the time when I found the gist, so happy that you did it. Great, thanks!

Comment: @JoelPurra sure thing! time will tell how brittle all of those paths are, haha

Comment: The official install does NOT work on 10.11 beta and any and all brew installs/work arounds that I've found do NOT work either.  I've had pdftk working on 10.9 and 10.10 without issues.

Comment: In case anyone is still looking, this is the download link that works on El Capitan. [https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.02-mac_osx-10.11-setup.pkg](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.02-mac_osx-10.11-setup.pkg)

Comment: 2021 Jan 12: Only thing that worked on macOS Big Sur was the link from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889993/293280. Using the download link from the official website downloads an old installer and you get a `zsh: bad CPU type in executable: pdftk` error.

Answer (score 80):

From `quantiverge` PR on brew:

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/quantiverge/homebrew-binary/pdftk/pdftk.rb
```

Comment: Worked for me on Mavericks. Sadly compiling from source has so many dependencies that it takes forever, so this is a nice shortcut for the meantime.

Comment: Still working on 10.9.5

Comment: Works on Yosemite (OS X 10.10) as well.. :)

Comment: We used the answer provided by Sean Leather, sorry couldn't find his @username it is the bottom answer on this post (as of this comment)

Comment: works on Yosemite 10.10.4 (y)

Comment: The official install does NOT work on 10.11 beta and any and all brew installs/work arounds that I've found do NOT work either. I've had pdftk working on 10.9 and 10.10 without issues.

Comment: Works on El Capitan 10.11 just fine!

Comment: @yannis I unfortunately had the same experience myself. Seems like it works and then just hangs.

Comment: Works on Sierra 10.12

Comment: The formula doesn't work with current brew, use `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/youtux/homebrew-binary/pdftk/pdftk.rb` from [youtux's PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-binary/pull/344) instead.

Comment: That just installs pdftk using the official pkg installer.

Comment: Up-to-date version of this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41243285/1492782 Command is: `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/turforlag/homebrew-cervezas/master/pdftk.rb`

Comment: Please note as of Aug 2017, none of the above works. The link posted by @JoshBuchea is the only thing that works.

Comment: 2018-06-12:  @JoshBuchea's link worked for me:  brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/turforlag/homebrew-cervezas/master/pdftk.rb

Comment: Error: pdftk: undefined method `sha1' for #<Class:0x0000000101c9d270>

Comment: 2021 Jan 12: Only thing that worked on macOS Big Sur was the link from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889993/293280. Using the download link from the official website downloads an old installer and you get a `zsh: bad CPU type in executable: pdftk` error.

Comment: ```Error: Non-checksummed download of pdftk formula file from an arbitrary URL is unsupported! `brew extract` or `brew create` and `brew tap-new` to create a formula file in a tap on GitHub instead.```

Answer (score 42):

I created a [pdftk homebrew tap](https://github.com/spl/homebrew-pdftk):

```
brew tap spl/pdftk
brew install pdftk
```

The [current formula](https://github.com/spl/homebrew-pdftk/blob/96b93a2cc5ea65b9e45edd486ece882fc6519949/pdftk.rb) depends on a specific compiler (`gcc48`) with a specific build flag (`enable-all-languages`). This is only be a problem if you happen to already have `gcc48` without the flag or if you have a different version of `gcc`. You can, of course, clone the formula and change it for your situation. But, unfortunately, nobody has answered my [question about alternative dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21115259/545794), so I don't know how to resolve this.

**Update 1 (2015-03-19)**: As of [this change](https://github.com/spl/homebrew-pdftk/pull/4) (described in my [solution to alternative dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28738539/545794)), the formula now supports multiple versions of `gcc` and different flags.

**Update 2 (2016-01-12)**: For OS X 10.11 El Capitan users, the source build of `pdftk` does not seem to work. There is a `.pkg` available at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248310/545794 . As of this date, PDF Labs has not yet released a source update that fixes the build.

Comment: it takes forever on my pro late 2011 to install gcc, not my way

Comment: I have found the same as @gaussblurinc. Mid 2011 iMac - taking an age to install the gcc dependency. Far more tempted to ditch pdftk and find a lighter alternative.

Comment: This took forever for me too. I used the answer below (install from `raw.github.com` and it's working fine)

Comment: @Aaron, Does my Homebrew tap also not work? It installs from source and not from the `.pkg`.

Comment: I tried to install from Homebrew and the install worked on 10.11, yes -- but the actual executable just hangs anytime you try to run commands. Warning: I've been using pdftk for over a year and installed from Homebrew and from www.pdflabs.com at times, and things worked fine. After 10.11 nothing works no matter how you install it. So pdftk is broke on 10.11. Here's my SO question on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505951/pdftk-server-on-os-x-10-11

Comment: @Aaron I've had the same broken experience myself so far.

Comment: @Poulsbo see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505951/pdftk-server-on-os-x-10-11

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! Yes, this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33248310/177203

Comment: Thanks for the comments, folks. I've updated my answer to point to the other answer. If you discover a way to build a working (possibly patched) `pdftk` from source on El Capitan, please let me know (either here or on GitHub).

Comment: Thanks for the second update... the docmunch cask tap seems to be hanging on an OSX patch. But the link to the .pkg helped me get it installed.

Comment: @SeanLeather the installation does not work anymore. It gets stuck at installing gcc 6.3.0

Comment: 2021 Jan 12: Only thing that worked on macOS Big Sur was the link from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60889993/293280. Using the download link from the official website downloads an old installer and you get a `zsh: bad CPU type in executable: pdftk` error.