# Alternative dependencies in a Homebrew formula (e.g. for use with gcc)

Tags: gcc, dependencies, homebrew

How can I describe alternative dependencies in a Homebrew formula? There are two different kinds I'm thinking of.

#### 1. Alternative packages

My formula can depend on package `P` or `Q`, but it must have one of them. So, I want either

```
depends_on 'P'
```

or

```
depends_on 'Q'
```

and I need at least one.

#### 2. Alternative flags for the same package

My formula requires another package `X` for building, and it needs a package `X` with one of two flags, `A` and `B`. That is, I want either

```
depends_on 'X' => [:build, 'A']
```

or

```
depends_on 'X' => [:build, 'B']
```

and I need at least one.

#### Example

A specific example of where these alternative dependencies would be useful is a formula depending on `gcc`. There are multiple packages for `gcc` (e.g. `gcc4[3-9]`), which could be supported by #1 above. `gcc` has a flag `enable-all-languages` which implies `enable-java`, so if a formula that requires `gcj` would use #2 to specify the alternative flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently discovered that it is possible to have dependencies conditionally determined by options. The general scheme is:

```ruby
option 'with-Q', 'Depend on Q instead of P'

depends_on 'P' if !build.with?('Q')
depends_on 'Q' if  build.with?('Q')
```

This can also be used for one dependency with alternative flags. This example is taken from my [`pdftk` formula](https://github.com/spl/homebrew-pdftk/blob/956920b0ccc5cf65941c05d091d4d7cd967e2f32/pdftk.rb):

```ruby
option 'with-java', 'Build gcc using --with-java instead of --with-all-languages'

depends_on 'gcc' => ['with-all-languages'] if !build.with?('java')
depends_on 'gcc' => ['with-java']          if  build.with?('java')
```

This is not a perfect solution to dealing with alternative dependencies, but it is probably the only one that Homebrew will support.