# How to solve "pdftk: Bad CPU type in executable" on Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, pdftk

I want to use pdftk but I always get this error `zsh: bad CPU type in executable: pdftk` I reinstalled pdftk and I changed the terminal from bsh to zsh as I found in my search for how to solve this error but without any success. I'm using the latest MacOS version "Catalina v10.15.4"

Answer (score 188, accepted):

This version of pdftk works on macOS Catalina (10.15).

https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.02-mac_osx-10.11-setup.pkg

The link on the website is not up to date. That means by clicking the download button on the website you get an old version.

Comment: Works on Big Sur (OSX 11) on M1 as well!

Comment: This "WHY" moment brought to you by the internet

Comment: This works (Big Sur on Intel).  Sent email to author, asking him to fix link.

Comment: Works on Monterey on M1 too

Comment: Confirm, works on M1 without any extra effort, just run the "pdftk" command as usual.

Comment: Work Perfectly on macOs Big Sur Version 11.6 by just installing the Packeg. Thanks Men.

Comment: Just to note now, this version is pretty out of date, and was throwing exception when trying to fill data into a PDF of mine. The version installed from homebrew as per gatorback's answer is 3.3.3 (and fixes the exceptions I was receiving)

Answer (score 18):

Homebrew:

```
brew install pdftk-java
```

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pdftk-java

Compatible with Catalina, Big Sur

Comment: pdftk-java can't decrypt some common format

Comment: This is correct way of doing in 2023

Comment: Note this is a Java *port* and is not the original pdftk. As such there may be bugs, known differences, and be feature incomplete or have additional features.

Comment: This is also worked in Mac monterey OS.

Answer (score 5):

Following Ben's answer, here is a bash script that search for the latest available PDFTK version from their website:

```
#!/bin/bash

PDFTK_VERSION="2.02"
MACOS_VERSION_MAJOR_START="10"
MACOS_VERSION_MAJOR_END="12"
MACOS_VERSION_MINOR_START="0"
MACOS_VERSION_MINOR_END="20"
DOWNLOAD_URL="https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-PDFTK_VERSION-mac_osx-MACOS_VERSION_MAJOR.MACOS_VERSION_MINOR-setup.pkg"

# Check if we want debug mode or not
if [[ "$1" == "debug" ]]; then
    DEBUG="YES"
fi

# Function that check if a file exist with curl
check_url_exist() {
    http_code=$( curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail -w '%{http_code}' "$1" 2>/dev/null )
    if [[ "$http_code" == "200" ]]; then
        echo "YES"
    else
        echo "NO"
    fi
}

echo "INFO - Searching for PDFTK version $PDFTK_VERSION, from MacOS version $MACOS_VERSION_MAJOR_START.$MACOS_VERSION_MINOR_START to $MACOS_VERSION_MAJOR_END.$MACOS_VERSION_MINOR_END."

# Search for available versions
MAJOR="$MACOS_VERSION_MAJOR_START"
while [ $MAJOR -le $MACOS_VERSION_MAJOR_END ]; do
    MINOR="$MACOS_VERSION_MINOR_START"
    while [ $MINOR -le $MACOS_VERSION_MINOR_END ]; do
        THIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=$( echo "$DOWNLOAD_URL" | sed -e "s|PDFTK_VERSION|$PDFTK_VERSION|g" | sed -e "s|MACOS_VERSION_MAJOR|$MAJOR|g" | sed -e "s|MACOS_VERSION_MINOR|$MINOR|g" )
        if [[ $( check_url_exist "$THIS_DOWNLOAD_URL" ) == "YES" ]]; then
            echo "FOUND     - Found version ! PDFTK:$PDFTK_VERSION, MacOS:$MAJOR.$MINOR. URL: $THIS_DOWNLOAD_URL"
        elif [[ "$DEBUG" == "YES" ]]; then
            echo "NOT FOUND - PDFTK:$PDFTK_VERSION, MacOS:$MAJOR.$MINOR. URL: $THIS_DOWNLOAD_URL"
        fi
        MINOR=$(( MINOR + 1))
        sleep 0.2
    done
    MAJOR=$(( MAJOR + 1))
done
```

And the result, at the date of 2022-10-15, is :

```
$ bash ./download_pdftk_mac.sh
INFO      - Searching for PDFTK version 2.02, from MacOS version 10.0 to 12.20.
FOUND     - Found version ! PDFTK:2.02, MacOS:10.6. URL: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.02-mac_osx-10.6-setup.pkg
FOUND     - Found version ! PDFTK:2.02, MacOS:10.11. URL: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.02-mac_osx-10.11-setup.pkg
```

Answer (score 1):

As a preliminary solution, I was successful in installing the Intel version of homebrew in /usr/local (in parallel to the M1 version in /opt/homebrew) using Apple's Rosetta 2 layer. The Intel packages (homebrew formulae) seem to work without any problem on the Apple M1 architecture. Both pdftk and pandoc work even without prefixing 'arch -x86_64' (e.g., the command 'pandoc sample.md -o sample.html' as in the example linked below).

Commands:

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
alias ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'
ibrew analytics off
ibrew install pdftk-java
ibrew install pandoc
```

Further information:

- [Homebrew on Apple Silicon](https://soffes.blog/homebrew-on-apple-silicon)
- [Install Homebrew with Rosetta](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6960#issuecomment-778698895)
- [Main thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/formulae.brew.sh/issues/467)

Comment: You can just install the package mentioned in Ben's answer, no extra hacks needed on M1.

Comment: Yes, as a workaround I had also mentioned it [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/formulae.brew.sh/issues/467#issuecomment-841846989). But it seems to be an old version (2.02). Now homebrew directly supports the M1 chip ("Apple Silicon"), with pdftk-java version 3.3.2, which I consider the better solution: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pdftk-java#default

Comment: I still get the error  pdftk                                       ✔  took 8s  at 08:05:51 PM
zsh: bad CPU type in executable: pdftk

Comment: If the Apple Silicon variant supported by [https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pdftk-java](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pdftk-java) doesn't work, the forum at [https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/-/issues](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/-/issues) might be the right place to ask for support. In my case it's working fine: pdftk-java: stable 3.3.2 (bottled).

Answer (score 1):

Using masOS 13.3.1:

```
brew install pdftk-java
brew link pdftk-java
```

Make sure you have java installed