# Split a bulk pdf into smaller pdfs using a command?

Tags: pdf, filesplitting

I have a pdf of 470 pages and I want split that into smaller pdfs using a command in Linux. I have hundreds of such pdfs and I want to automate the process. Is there a way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a PDF in two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776582/split-a-pdf-in-two)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is `pdfseparate`:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pdfseparate.1.html

You can call it from a shell script to automate the splitting.